# How to index to a particular commit without touching HEAD or any other ref?

Tags: git, git-plumbing

Basically, I'm looking for the *opposite* of `git reset --soft` - ideally a plumbing command.

I need to modify a particular index file (set via `GIT_INDEX_FILE`) to point to a specific commit, without altering any ref like HEAD (or anything else).

Is there a command that can modify an index in this manner? How can I achieve this?

Comment: `git read-tree` and `git update-index` could help.

Comment: Also `git restore --staged`

Comment: @ElpieKay: `git read-tree`  seems to do what I need, thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer.